# PDF Document does not display when creating control dynamically

Tags: c#, pdf

I have an application that I want to display multiple PDF documents. If I define the control at design time I can load a document and display it, but when I dynamically create the control during run time I cannot get it to display. The document is being displayed in a tab.

Here is my code...

```
AxAcroPDF newPDF = new AxAcroPDF();
newPDF.CreateControl();
newPDF.Width = selectedTab.Width;
newPDF.Height = selectedTab.Height;
newPDF.LoadFile(filePath);

selectedTab.Controls.Add(newPDF);
newPDF.Show();
newPDF.Visible = true;
```

How do I get the PDF to display?

Comment: try reversing this line `newPDF.Show();
newPDF.Visible = true;` 
set the .Visible property first.. also are you sure that the selectedTab is the one that you are expecting.. what is the selectedTab Index when you are debugging the code..?

Comment: Switching the visible/show statements didn't make any difference. Yes I can see which tab is currently active when I debug the code. When the program starts there is only one tab, which is the one selected and I the pdf doesn't show on that tab.

Comment: perhaps there is a setting in the designer that's being overwritten when you run the code.. I can't think of anything else off the top of my head..

Comment: Maybe you should use OnPropertyChange() to notify your view an update ?

Comment: I can't find a method called OnPropertyChange()

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what worked for me...

```
AxAcroPDF newPDF = new AxAcroPDF();
selectedTab.Controls.Add(newPDF);

newPDF.CreateControl();
newPDF.Width = selectedTab.Width;
newPDF.Height = selectedTab.Height;

newPDF.LoadFile(filePath);
newPDF.Show();
```

For some reason it doesn't like the PDF control being added to the tab after the CreateControl() method is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Width` and `Height` but `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` from the SelectedTab. Under certain circumstances the non actuals may report zero sizes.

Otherwise hard code height and width to see if that provides an insight as to whether it is showing up, but hidden.

Comment: The tabPage object doesn't have properties ActualWidth and ActualHeight

Comment: @Gary What happens if you hard code the height and width?

Comment: @Gary is the filepath to the loaded PDF the same? Also maybe set `IsEnabled` to true.